# Cocoa: best way to disable all controls in a view

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, user-interface

In an OS X app, I have various text fields, buttons, and other controls all inside of a scroll view. Is there a way to disable the elements inside the scroll view all at once?

I'd like to avoid calling `setEnabled:` on each and every item, so that maintenance is easier if I want to add more controls to the scroll view later on.

I'd like to emphasize that this is for an OS X app, so techniques that work in iOS don't necessarily apply here.

Comment: you could add a category to uiview and make a method that propagates the property down the hierarchy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can iterate through all the `subviews` of the content view, and call `setEnabled:` on all of them. This might break the scroll view by disabling some internal view, so don't iterate on the `subview` property of the scroll view itself. To prevent calling `setEnabled:` on views that don't have an enabled property, use `respondsToSelector:@selector(setEnabled:)` to check.

Answer (score 6):

For the sake of the record, here is an NSView category I use in my Cocoa apps:
https://github.com/ardalahmet/DisableSubviews

It makes it easy to enable/disable subviews at once and it also offers much flexibility.
You can make such calls:

```
[scrollView disableSubviews:YES];

[self.window.contentView disableSubviews:YES
                                  ofType:[NSTextField class]];

[someView disableSubviews:YES
                   filter:^BOOL (NSView *v) {
                       return [v isKindOfClass:[NSTextField class]] &&
                              (((NSTextField *) v).stringValue.length < 1);
                   }];

[otherView disableSubviews:disable
                  startTag:3
                    endTag:7];
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks tons, this is just what I was looking for. +99 I wish. +1 must suffice.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this tasks like this easily with bindings. You must have an instance of your controller class in your XIB for the following steps, but the technique does not require this - you can do the setup programmatically if you'd prefer.

1. Add a `BOOL` property to your controller class, say `scrollItemsEnabled`
2. In IB/designer pane of Xcode 4 open your XIB
3. For each controller you'd like enabled/disabled select it and in the bindings pane of the inspector link the `Enabled` binding to `scrollItemsEnabled` property of your controller class instance
4. Now in your code setting the property will enable/disable all the items together

Answer (score 4):

Here is a NSView Category I used in my project which works fine.

```
//Code for NSView+Custom.h
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
@interface NSView (Custom)
    -(void) setEnabled:(BOOL) isEnabled;
@end

//Code for NSView+Custom.m

#import "NSView+Custom.h"

@implementation NSView (Custom)

-(void) setEnabled:(BOOL) isEnabled{

    for (NSView* subView in self.subviews) {

        if ([subView isKindOfClass:[NSControl class]]) {

            [(NSControl*)subView setEnabled:isEnabled];
        }else  if ([subView isKindOfClass:[NSView class]]) {

            [subView setEnabled:isEnabled];
        }
    }
}

@end
```

Answer (score -3):

I like to do this in the view controller with one property (a BOOL called userInteractionEnabled or something similar) and then check it in the appropriate delegate methods in the view controller:

```
 - (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextfield *)txtField {
      if (!self.userInteractionEnabled) {
           return NO;
      }
      // Your other logic

      return YES;
 }
```

Do this for each control type that you use.

Comment: UI... are not for OS X
And NSViews don't have userInteractionEnabled property

Comment: @ArnaudLays While true, this was for example purposes only.  What I do is to **create** the property (as I said, you **call** it that **or something similar**) and check it from the appropriate delegate methods (as I said 4-1/2 years ago when I wrote this answer....)

Answer (score -4):

Try this

```
[scrollView setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
```

Comment: Unfortunately, you do more than disable the controls this way: you also disable the scrolling.  This may or may not be acceptable.

Comment: userInteractionEnabled doesn't exist on NSViews

Comment: It does on UIView's (which is what UIScrollView inherits from).

Comment: @Inafziger - UIViews are for iOS.. this question is for OS X

Comment: Ahhh, true!  I missed that, sorry!