# MacOS EnableWindow equivalent

Tags: c++, objective-c, cocoa

I'm looking for a way to block keyboard and mouse events into an `NSWindow` object, similar to Windows' [EnableWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enablewindow).

I'm aware of `setIgnoresMouseEvents` but it doesn't do the trick.
Does anyone know a good way to find a similar behaviour ?

Comment: Possibly a dup: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619316/cocoa-best-way-to-disable-all-controls-in-a-view/10470776

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cocoa: best way to disable all controls in a view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619316/cocoa-best-way-to-disable-all-controls-in-a-view)